# R function to display only the 20% highest values of a column

Tags: r, indexing

I'm new to R. I have a matrix of numeric values and want to display only the highest 20% of a specific column.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use `top_n` or `m1[,1][m1[,1] >= quantile(m1[,1], 0.8)]`

Answer (score 1):

With a `data.table` object, you would do:

```r
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(m1)
col <- colnames(df)
m1[get(col) >= quantile(get(col), probs = .8)]
```

This is probably the fastest method if you have a voluminous dataset

Answer (score 0):

We can use `quantile` to create a logical vector and extract the elements from the column (here it is assumed that it is the first column)

```
m1[,1][m1[,1] >= quantile(m1[,1], 0.8)]
```

---

If it is a data.frame, we can use `top_frac`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(m1) %>%
    top_frac(n = 0.2, wt = col1)
```

Or with `slice_max`

```
as.data.frame(m1) %>%
     slice_max(col1, prop = 0.2)
```